# The Android service is not responding

Tags: android

I am developing an Android anti-theft application and would like to implement the backup contacts function. I am not expert in Android and quite new in it, so I just simply implement a simple coding in retrieving the contact names together with the phone numbers and attach all these into a string message and send it over the email. I would like this to be one of my services in the application, meaning user is not informed with this backup contact service. I did run this function independently as an application and it works. But when i move this to my anti-theft apps as a service, it does not work... kindly need help from everyone to help me check out the problem... thanks...

```
public class BackupContacts extends Service{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    String msg = "**********Backup Phone Contacts**********\n\n";
    SharedPreferences pref;
    public static String filenames = "AntiTheft";
    String email;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pref = getSharedPreferences(filenames, 0);
    email = pref.getString("keyemail", "");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId); 
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    retrieveContacts();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void retrieveContacts(){

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.NUMBER));

        msg += name + "\t\t\t\t\t" + number + "\n";         
    }

    try{
        sendMail();
    } catch(MessagingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendMail() throws MessagingException{

    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
    String to = email;
    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String from = "testing@gmail.com";
    // Email Password
    String password = "abc123";
    // Assuming you are sending email from GMail SMTP
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    // Get system properties
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    // Setup mail server
    //properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

    // Create a default MimeMessage object.
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    // Set From: header field of the header.
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    // Set To: header field of the header.
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    // Set Subject: header field
    message.setSubject("This is the Backup Contacts Email!");
    // Now set the actual message
    //message.setText(msg.toString());

    //BodyPart always come along with MultiPart (For sending attachment in email)
    //Create the message part
    BodyPart msgBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    //Fill up the message
    msgBodyPart.setText(msg);

    //Create a multipart message
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    //Set the text message part
    multipart.addBodyPart(msgBodyPart);
    //Set the complete message part
    message.setContent(multipart);

    // Send message
    //Transport.send(message);
    try{
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect(host, from, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        transport.close();
    }catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have declared this class as a Service in `Manifest.xml`?

Inside the `<application>` tag, put the following piece of code:

```
<service android:name=".BackupContacts" />
```